# JavaCard - AID not saved? array gets overwritten with the last element

Tags: arrays, javacard

I am encountering a problem when I create a Directory File. I am obviously not creating a new Object, but only the reference - just still not sure where/why!

```
DirectoryFile[] arrayDF = new DirectoryFile[8];
```

now when I create a new DF:

```
numapp++;
arrayDF[numApp] = new DirectoryFile(aid);
```

and right after that I simply print them out in a loop

```
APDU apdu = APDU.getCurrentAPDU();
apdu.setOutgoing();
apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) 21);

for (i = 2; i <= numApp; i++) {          
     apdu.sendBytesLong(arrayDF[i].getAID(), (short) 0, (short) 6);

}
```

where numApp is the number of Applications/DFs, starting with 2, since 1 is the MasterFile.
for aid = a00000000001 I get

```
A0 00 00 00 00 01 90 00                         .........
Status: No Error
```

as response
for aid = a00000000002 I get

```
A0 00 00 00 00 02 A0 00 00 00 00 02 90 00    ................
Status: No Error
```

for aid = a00000000003 I get

```
A0 00 00 00 00 03 A0 00 00 00 00 03 A0 00 00 00 00 03 90 00    ................
    Status: No Error
```

So all the already saved AIDs get somehow overwritten.
In DirectoryFile I do as follows

```
public DirectoryFile(byte[] aid) {
        super(aid);
        for (byte i = 0; i < activatedFiles.length; i++)
            activatedFiles[i] = false;

    }
```

where super(aid) calls the constructor of File.java

```
     public abstract class File {
            public byte[] aid = new byte[6];

            public File (byte[] aid) {
                this.aid = aid; 
            }
            public byte[] getAID() {
                return aid;
            }
     }
```

Where is my mistake in doing this?

After a bit more testing I at least found out that the classes (DirectoryFile, File) should work just fine:

```
 aDF[j] = new DirectoryFile(aid1);
      j++;
      aDF[j] = new DirectoryFile(aid2);
      j++;
      aDF[j] = new DirectoryFile(aid3);
      j++;
      aDF[j] = new DirectoryFile(aid4);
      j++;
      APDU apdu = APDU.getCurrentAPDU();
      apdu.setOutgoing();
      byte[] myi = new byte[1];
      apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) 28);
      for (j = 0; i < 4; i++) {      
        myi[0] = i;       
        apdu.sendBytesLong(myi, (short) 0, (short) 1);
        apdu.sendBytesLong(aDF[i].getAID(), (short) 0, (short) 6);
```

will print

```
00 A0 00 00 00 00 01 01 A0 00 00 00 00 02 02 A0    ................
    00 00 00 00 03 03 A0 00 00 00 00 04 90 00          ..............
Status: No Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `File` implementation is not correct, you first generate an array of six bytes, but instead of copying the AID into it - using `Util.arrayCopy()` - you simply assign it the reference to the passed in array, throwing a way the reference to the previously generated `aid` buffer. So if the values of the passed in AID changes value, the value of the AID in `File` also changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I tried it with a `Util.arrayCopy(aid, (short) 0, this.aid, (short) 0, (short) 6);` instead of `this.aid = aid;` but the results won't change (unfortunately)!